# Reading from a file into a List using C++

Tags: c++, list, file, input

I'm a little new to using file input/output so bear with me.

I've got a function called `RunList(filename)`, that takes the name of the file as input and returns nothing. The file will have the format of having one line that is useless and I plan on using ignore() on and then the next line which is important has the format

"i 1 2 3 4 5 ...."

where the numbers go on for a very long way, about 250000 or so.

So what I want to do is to open this file, ignore the first line, and then for each number in the file I want to use the function `void insert(x, p)` which is a function I have defined to insert x after the current iterator position p. The end result is that I want to have my list contain all of the numbers in the file after the "i" and be in the same order. I have also defined the functions `ListItr find(x)` and `ListItr first()` which will return the iterator to the position that views x and to the first potion respectively.

Could anyone provide me with a means of doing this? I was thinking of using a for() loop and taking in each word at a time from the file and using my function to insert each element, but I'm a little lost as to how to do this, as I said I'm very new to using file input/output.

So, my RunList function currently looks something like this, although obviously its not finished nor does it really work, hence me needing some help on it.

```
    void Runlist(filename){
        ifstream in;
        in.open(filename); 
        in.ignore(1000, '\n');         //this is me trying to ignore the first line
        for (int i, i < 250000, i++){
            int number;
            in >> number
            void insert(number, i)
        }
```

}

But the plan was, I select the file, ignore the first line, then set up a for loop where i can use my void insert(number, i) to insert each number, but then i don't really understand how to read in each word at a time, or to preserve the order because if I just kept using the function on each number over and over then the list would have the numbers in the reverse order I believe.

Comment: and whats the question

Comment: Please show what relevant code you have, and what the specific problem is.  This is not a site where someone will write your code for you.

Comment: cool plan, what problems in your code have you have you run into that you need help with? Also, you might want to post that code as well.

Comment: Alright, i'll start copying over my code now. The part that I need help with is that I'm very new to the file mechanics and don't really understand how to go through the file and read in each number and using my function on them while preserving the order.

Comment: Since you are new, try **searching** StackOverflow for "read file list".

Comment: Also search for things like `fstream` and `ifstream` here on StackOverflow (SO).  Outside of SO, review this for fstream: [std::basic_fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

Comment: Don't "copy over [your] code". Present your debugging [testcase](http://sscce.org). If you don't have one yet, you are days away from asking for help from the internet.

Comment: You do not specify void for the return type of the function, either; not that it is the main issue. Also, instead of ignore, you could just drop the first line when reading by using getline once. Your for loop usage is also pretty invalid: commas instead of semi-colons, no initialization of `i`, and so on. We do not see insert either. `i` is not an "iterator" either, so probably you meant index. Please show us a tested code that at least compiles and we can concentrate on runtime issues!

Comment: Alright, I'll start searching for those things now, ty

Comment: Whups and yeah added in the void, copying over from an ssh terminal so I couldn't just copy/paste too quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- You do not specify void for the return type of the function.
- Instead of ignore, you could just drop the first line when reading by using getline once.
- Your for loop usage is also pretty invalid: commas instead of semi-colons
- No initialization of i, and so on.
- insert is not shown, but you could probably use append anyway since that is what you seem to be doing.
- i is not an "iterator" either, so probably you meant index.
- You are having a function declaration in the middle of the function rather than calling it.

This pseudo code should get you going about understanding the input file stream class and its usage for this in C++:

```
void Runlist(filename)
{
    ifstream in(filename, ifstream::in);
    in.getline(0, 1024);
    int number;
    while (in >> number)
        append(number);
    in.close();
}
```

Disclaimer: this pseudo code is missing proper error checking, and so on.